# Grails - Problems with some services after starting the server

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails

We are using grails version 2.4.3 and tomcat 7

As our project is growing (it is 3 years old and contains around 120 services already) we are having more an more problems every time that we restart the server. This means that after every deployment we need to double check if all the services are working, and otherwise we need to restart again and try again, in certain ocassions we needed to restart 4 or 5 times (the number of times is undefined), and after that started working all the services.

Usually after one crashing if we check the logs we can see an error message, saying that Hibernate is getting duplicates from the db (in a table that it is using in that service, but it is a different table every time), and after restarting n-times, once it is working, we don't have this error anymore

Had anyone else this type of behavior with this version of grails or with Tomcat?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `duplicates from the db (in a table that it is using in that service` is your first point of research as in the exact error message.  There isn't much anyone can help you with. The very least you should have done is output actual error hiding your domain / class path details

Comment: hi Vahid, thanks for taking some time to response, I assume that the error is not important, because as I said, after restarting the error goes away, in case of really having duplicates in the db that wouldn't be the case. What I'm asking is if anyone is having problems with grails deployments, not regarding that particular error.

Comment: maybe you have some event / process that isn't being captured in the logs and it is possibly worth looking into firstly ensuring full logging is on and also worth enabling sql logging to see within app to see what is going on to try to understand issue better. The fact it starts after a few attempts sounds like either some event or some local data. hard to say withouth logs analysis etc .